# Golang channel blocking operations

Tags: go, channel

I'm trying to stop child (or chained) go channels, but operation is blocking (e.g listener with wait network connection)

Because operation is blocking, for and case never enter in case <-quit

How to solve this ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    quit := make(chan bool)

    fmt.Println("Starting Channel 001")
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-quit:
                fmt.Println("Channel 001 stopped")
                // Expected result: hangFunction stop execution looping
                return
            default:
                hangFunction()
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

            }
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println("Closing channel 001")
    close(quit)

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Hour)
}

func hangFunction() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("[hangFunction] Looping")
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have to monitor the channel from within `hangFunction`.

Comment: Unblock the network operation by closing the listener. It will be helpful to show the actual code that blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `for{}` loop in `hangFunction()` which is blocking forever:

```golang
func hangFunction() {
    fmt.Println("[hangFunction] Looping")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

Or you can monitor the channel from within the function as @Adrian mentionned in the comments, by doing something like:

```golang
func hangFunction(quit chan bool) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-quit:
            return
        default:
            fmt.Println("[hangFunction] Looping")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }
}
```

which is not ideal as you have the same `select{}` block twice (in your main and in the function). It will work tho.